# Azure ServiceBusProcessor takes a long time to stop

Tags: c#, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm playing around with sending messages through the Azure Service Bus library Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus. I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues) and sending/processing a single message.

When calling processor.StopProcessingAsync(), the action takes about a minute (each single time). When looking in the Azure portal, all messaged processed. I have no clue why it takes so long for the processor the stop even though there are no messages on the queue.

It seems like it takes the (exact) same amount of time each time. If anyone could point me to why it takes such a long time and how to reduce it (configuration/setup?), I would be more than thankful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your comment. Let's say for scaling purposes. When I'd want to scale up and down again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. While going through the source code, I found that there's a default "wait time" after a receiver was started which is 60 seconds. This can be lowered by setting [TryTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusretryoptions.trytimeout?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_ServiceBus_ServiceBusRetryOptions_TryTimeout) on ServiceBusClientOptions.ServiceBusRetryOptions.

See:
[ServiceBusRetryOptions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/4d04a1fab4277198f27206e6050210f9e8b84497/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Primitives/ServiceBusRetryOptions.cs)
[AmqpReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsyncInternal](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Amqp/AmqpReceiver.cs)

Comment: If this works, please mark this answer to end this question.:)

Answer (score 0):

> I tested this, it works as expected:

```
var clientOptions = new ServiceBusClientOptions();
clientOptions.RetryOptions.TryTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString, clientOptions);
```

> sets the timeout to 5 seconds.